# ssl error while using php curl to make api call

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

i am using api to send sms. i am using  php curl to post sms data like phone number and sms text on api url for example https//sms.example.com

most of the time my api calls are working fine getting propper response.

but since last few days i am getting following curl error while posting data on sms url:

openSSL SSL connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to sms.example.com:443

i using following ssl related setting in my curl request

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```

my sms vendor support team suggested me to use tls1.2 protocol so i added following line of code in curl request

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION=>CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
```

still getting same  error.

my sms application server is behind firewall.

can anyone help me figure out what is the issue ? and possible solution.